# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly for neo4j powershell script

Tags: powershell, neo4j, invoke-webrequest

I have a powershell script I am trying to use to run queries on a neo4j database. Following the steps here: https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSNeo4j.

The issue is that when I run the code with proper creds and URL, I get a connection closed error. I am having trouble believing it is the library this happens with a 'Invoke-WebRequest' command too. Assuming that my creds and url are correct, is there something I am missing?

Code:

```
Import-Module PSNeo4j


$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "dummypswd" -AsPlainText -Force

$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'username', $password

Set-PSNeo4jConfiguration -Credential $Cred -BaseUri 'http://localhost:7687'

# Did we connect?
Get-Neo4jUser
```

Comment: I haven't used neo4j from PowerShell for quite some time, but shouldn't the uri be either `http://localhost:7474` or `bolt://localhost:7687` (or perhaps `neo4j://localhost:7687`)?

Comment: I get an error saying that bolt is invalid? Yet on python, bolt works...